# "Start tag head seen but an element of the same type was already open", but I don’t have a duplicate <head>

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am validating my web page code in the W3Schools and it keeps giving me this error message:

> Error: Start tag `head` seen but an element of the same type was already open.
>   From line 5, column 1; to line 5, column 6
>
> ```
> "utf-8">↩↩<head>↩<style>
> ```

I have checked through my code and I can't see where I have made a duplicate of a head tag, can someone help me out please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
<style>table,th, td{border:1.5px solid red;} td{ padding: 15px;}</style>
<title> Index </title>
</head>

<body>
<h1> Online store for cheese  </h1>

<table style="width:100">
<tr>
<th>Cheese name</th>
<th>Origin</th>
<th>Years to age</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><a href="https://www.thecheeseworks.co.uk/old-amsterdam"> Gouda  </a> </td>
<td> Netherlands</td>
<td> 1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td> <a href="taleggio.html">Taleggio</a></td>
<td> Italy(Lombardy)</td>
<td> 6-10 weeks </td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Parmigiano-Reggiano</td>
<td>Italy</td>
<td> 1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Manchego</td>
<td>Spain</td>
<td> 60 days to 2 years</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Monterey Jack</td>
<td>USA</td>
<td> 1 month</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Cheddar </td>
<td>England</td>
<td> 1</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Emmental</td>
<td>Switzerland</td>
<td> 4 months</td>
</tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you really mean a validator from W3Schools instead of the W3C validator? (note that W3Schools has nothing to do with the W3C)

Answer (score 2):

In your third line you have a `<meta charset="utf-8">` before your `<head>` start tag. Having a meta element after the `<html>` start tag automatically opens the head element before the meta element, which causes your explicit `<head>` tag to be detected as a duplicate.

Simply move your `<meta charset="utf-8">` underneath the `<head>` tag to resolve this error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>table,th, td{border:1.5px solid red;} td{ padding: 15px;}</style>
<title> Index </title>
</head>
```

(You can also remove the `<head>` tag entirely and it would validate, too, but having a `</head>` end tag without its start tag looks funny, even if the start tag isn't *strictly* necessary.)

Comment: I had a similar issue, where an invalid attribute in my `html` tag caused some duplicate tags to be implicitly generated.